# Seting up GIT server with anonymous user

Tags: git, gitolite, centos6.5

I have already set gitolite on my VPS, currently every time I want to push/pull i need to include git username. For example:

```
git clone git-username@domain-name:repository-name
```

Is there anyway I can exclude the username to do the git command shell like

```
git clone domain-name:repository-name
```

I really appreciate if some one can help me to set my git configuration. Here is my vps info in case its needed:

1. Centos 6.5
2. Git 1.7.1
3. Gitolite3 v3.6-1-g8b7c50a

Answer (score 1):

If you are cloning over ssh, you should be able to specify what username to use for a given host as described [here](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996#modify-the-ssh-config).

It will probably look something like

```
Host domain-name
    HostName domain-name
    User git-username
```

*You may also want to update git to something more recent, currently most recent version is 2.3.*

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that it must be work from all client's computer. Your answer looks like we have to set in ~/.ssh/config for all client's computer. Is there any other way to config from server side?

Comment: @bbc_danang I think ssh defaults to sending the current user's name if one is not specified.  You could create an an account with ssh access for all of the users that will connect to this server, but from a security point of view that's a terrible idea.

Comment: It's okay as long as it can be done. Why would I need to secure my vps if it doesn't require password to login. This is passwordless vps, only accept authorized key. And fiew people know about this vps.. This is a private vps for playing around with my student.